# Check whether wget succeeds in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3 project, in the controller, I use the command `wget` to download files from the Internet and place them on my server. In the controller, I want to check whether `wget` succeeds in downloading the files. How can I perform that check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system) for the `system` command:

> system returns true if the command gives zero exit status, false for
>   non zero exit status. Returns nil if command execution fails.

So, you could do something like this:

```
if system('wget fail')
   puts 'Success!'
else
   puts 'Fail!'
end
```